# Is it normal that our sharepoint on-premises 2013 does not have WSS_Loging database

Tags: 2013, administration, database, wss-logging

we have a sharepoint farm 2013 (license type = SharePoint Server with Standard Client Access License) , now we are facing an issue that the "Usage reports" for our sites will always be empty (0 views). so i login to out database server, to check the permission for the "WSS_UsageApplication".. but i have noted that our database server miss the "WSS_Logging" database, here is our database list:-

[image]

so is this normal? and how i can check if this database server actually exists or have been removed? also if this database was removed, then can we still access and use our sites? as we did not face any issues, except for the "Usage Report" been empty...

but when i checked the logging database name inside our CA >> Monitoring >> "
Configure usage and health data collection" >> i found the name as follow "WSS_UsageApplication" and not "WSS_Logging":-
[image]

so am i missing anything? as on all the farms i worked on i always find a database named "WSS_Logging"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you dont have Usage service configured or it is deleted or its database deleted.

- Open the Central admin > go to Application management > Manage Service Application.
- On this page look for "Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application", if it is there then click on it. if it is not their then thats means service never provisioned or deleted.
- if it exist, click on it and on "Configure usage and health data collection " go to the bottom of the page, you will see the DB server name and DB name as well.
- Now check that db server for the db...if not exists then time for restore.

Comment: can you check my update question,, seems the DB name in my case is "WSS_UsageApplication" and not "WSS_Logging".. so i should be fine?

Comment: it should be fine, you can pick whatever name you want.